# Analyzing Sensor Data stored in cassandra and draw graphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, cassandra, analytics

I'm collecting data from different sensors and write them to a Cassandra database. 
The Sensor-ID accts as a partition key, the timestamp of the sensors data as clustering column. Additionally a value of the sensor is stored.
Each sensor collects something about 30000 to 60000 values a day.

The simplest thing I wane do is draw a graph showing this data. This is not a problem for a few hours but when showing a week or even a longer range, all the data has to be loaded into the backend (a rails application) for further processing. This isn't really fast with my test dataset and won't be faster in production I think.

So my question is, how to speed this up. I thought about pre-processing the data directly in the database but it seems, that Cassandra isn't able to do such things.

For a graph with a width of 1000px it isn't interesting to draw ten thousands of points - so it would be interesting to gather only relevant, pre-aggregated data from the database.
For example, when showing the data for a whole day in a graph with a width of 1000px, it would be enough to take 1000 average values (this would be an average clustered by 86seconds - 60*60*24 / 1000).

Is this a good approach? Or are there other techniques fasten this up? How would I handle this with database? Create a second Table and store some average values? But the resolution of the graph may change...

Other approaches would be drawing mean values by day, week, month and so on. Maybe vor this a second table could do a good job!

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is all about letting you write and read your data quickly. Think of it as just a data store. It can't (really) do any processing on that data.

If you want to do operations on it, then you are going to need to put the data into something else. [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) is quite popular for building computation clusters for processing data from Cassandra, but without knowing exactly the scale you need to operate at, then that may be overkill.

Another option which might suit you is to aggregate data on the way in, or perhaps in nightly jobs. This is how OLAP is often done with other technologies. This can work if you know in advance what you need to aggregate. You could build your sets into hourly, daily, whatever, then pull a smaller amount of data into Rails for graphing (and possibly aggregate it even further to exactly meet the desired graph requirements).

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of storing, aggregating, and graphing your sensor data, you might consider [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) which does basically everything you describe.  Its main limitation is it does not store raw data, but instead stores aggregated, interpolated values.  (If you need the raw data, you can still use Cassandra for that.)

Answer (score 0):

AndySavage is onto something here when it comes to precomputing aggregate values. This does require you to understand in advance the sorts of metrics you'd like to see from the sensor values generally.

You correctly identify the limitation of a graph in informing the viewer. Questions you need to ask really fall into areas such as:

- When you aggregate are you interested in the mean, median, spread of the values?
- What's the biggest aggregation that you're interested in?
- What's the goal of the data visualisation - is it really necessary to be looking at a whole year of data?
- Are outliers the important part of the dataset?

Each of these questions will lead you down a different path with visualisation and the application itself too.

Once you know what you're wanting to do, an ETL process harnessing some form of analytical processing will be needed. This is where the Hadoop world would be useful investigating.

Regarding your decision to use Cassandra as your timeseries historian, how is that working for you? I'm looking at technical solutions for a similar requirement at the moment and it's one of the options on the table.